# How to restore Eclipse shortcut keys from exported .CSV?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

You can simply export your shortcuts settings in Eclipse going to Window > Preferences > General > Keys > button Export CSV...
But how to restore shortcuts from this csv?

Comment: This is not programming related.

Comment: Do you still have access to the IDE with the other keys setup?

Comment: @Pepe Eclipse is an IDE or a tool used for programming.  This is definitely **related** to programming.  The OP didn't just start the Eclipse tag.

Comment: Funny, I see the export option but nothing about import.  :-(

Comment: @mikemil I think only the `.epf` files can be imported and the success is often spotty.

Comment: @Pepe : I say this might just fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers"  (also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: This is another example of a good question ruined by rep-mining editors. I would have certainly preferred to be on an answered SO question right now, about to restore my shortcut keys.. alas, the search continues..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if .csv file is OK to restore settings. But for .epf files it can be done via file->import->general->preferences. When you select the preferences, then you will see this screen:

[image: import preferences]

Then you can select your .epf settings. It will automatically knows which type of settings file it is when you select the .epf file.